# Symmetries of a regular 5-sided polyhedron

Tags: permutations, symmetry

Given a 5-sided regular polyhedron, with labelled vertices, how would I label all of the symmetries in the form of a permutation?

I cannot find any similar problems to this, nor can I find an image of a 5-sided regular polyhedron. It seems as though such an object does not exist. How would I go about solving this?

My understanding is that a symmetry is a reflection along an axis such that the shape of the object does not change. How can I solve this problem without an image of the shape in question?

Is it merely the case that each symmetry is just the swapping of two vertices? I know that there are 10 such permutations.

Comment: What does "5-sided" mean here? (Assuming "polyhedron" refers exclusively to 3-dimensional objects). Because there is a regular polyhedron with all faces pentagons (so "5-sided faces"), but there is indeed no regular polyhedron with five faces.

Comment: "Consider a regular 5-sided polyhedron, with the vertices labelled 1 through 5".

Is there a mistake in the problem set?